# iOS - Disable Answers but keep Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-answers

Is there an update on Fabric to disable Answers but keep Crashlytics from Fabric? The latest answers on this topic on Stack Overflow were last year so I'm hoping by now that there is an update that can solve this issue. Our team keeps seeing greater analytics when we're testing on a staging environment which can be annoying because we want to know real data only.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. There have been no changes on this front. If you want to keep debug and production data separate, either creating two organizations and conditionally changing your API key or using two separate bundle identifiers or package names are the recommend workarounds.

Comment: Is this ever likely to change? (It *seems* like a pretty reasonable requirement to be able to offer the app user the option to disable anonymous user data capture.)

Comment: I can't comment on our potential roadmap. If you want to allow users to opt-out, you definitely can, but it is for both analytics and crash reporting.